# Django Elastic APM Trace logs message missing

Tags: django, logging, elastic-stack

I have Django-elastic APM setup, that's sends traces and logs to elk stack. Its actually works, but not as I need. I get trace, I get metadata, even logs received (2nd pic)
[image: I get trace, I get metadata, even logs received (2nd pic)]

But, problem is, I don't get any messages in logs section and I didn't find how to customize fields.

[image: no messages!]

But! When I search directly in logs, I see following: Message exist
[image: Message exist]

Finally, when I search it discover section, I can see even more info. Fields, I actually need.[image: fields, I actually need]

**QUESTION**

So, there is my questions. Is it possible to add at least message info to transaction logs (first pic), Is it possible to at least add custom fields to logs section (2nd pic) Also, is there a way to make logs at least clickable? (Also 2nd pic, I mean its just plain text I have to go to discover and use this info like ctrl+c ctrl+v)
Finally, why logs are marked as Errors, if its just a logs, and used like logs? I tried to set different levels as debug, or info, as u see in 2nd screen, but it still comes like error and it goes in apm-7.14-error* index.

Here's my logging settings:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': 'velname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
    'elasticapm': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'elasticapm.contrib.django.handlers.LoggingHandler',
    },

},
'loggers': {
    'meditations': {
        'handlers': ['elasticapm'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
```

}
And that's how I send logs:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('meditations')
logger.info(
    'info',
    extra={
        'request.data': request.data,
        'user_utc_time': request.user.fcmTime
    }
)
logger.warning(
    'log',
    extra={
        'request.data': request.data,
        'user_utc_time': request.user.fcmTime
    }
)
logger.debug(
    'debug',
    extra={
        'request.data': request.data,
        'user_utc_time': request.user.fcmTime
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Elastic logs don't provide debug-info-warn logs, its used only to pass high-level (error-critical) logs and doesn't hold message. If u came here, u should use Django logging and send it to elastic via logstash or filebeat. I used logstash.

Comment: can you share how you integrate logstash with django?